# Yii2 Assigning Selected value on Dependant Dropdown

Tags: javascript, yii2

In Yii2 i have a form with 2 dependant dropdowns on selection of both a div containing details displays. I have to assign selected value if it is provided and i have assigned one of the dropdown with it, Question is how to assign the second dropdown with selected value.

```
<div class="col-sm-6">
<?= $form->field($SasModel, 'all_batch_id')->dropDownList(ArrayHelper::map(app\modules\course\models\Batches::find()->where(['is_status' => 0])->all(),'batch_id','batch_name', 'batchCourse.course_name'), 
    [
        'options' => [$_GET['batchid'] => ['Selected'=>'selected']],
        'prompt'=>'Select Batch',
        'onchange'=>'
            $.get( "'.Url::toRoute('subjectsallocatesem/studsection').'", { id: $(this).val() } )
                .done(function( data ) {
                    $( "#'.Html::getInputId($SasModel, 'semester_id').'" ).html( data );
                }
            );
        '    
    ]); 

?>
</div>

<div class="col-md-6">
<?= $form->field($SasModel, 'semester_id')->dropDownList(
    [ 'prompt'=>'---Select Semester---' ],
    [ 'onchange'=>'this.form.submit()' ]
); ?>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Create method in Semester model:

```
public static function getBatchSemster( $batch_id = NULL) 
{

    if(!empty($batch_id)) {
        $semester = self::find()->andWhere(['batch_id_in_semester_model' => $batch_id])->all();
        $results = yii\helpers\ArrayHelper::map($semester, 'sem_id', 'sem_name');
        return $results;
   }
   else {
     return $results[];
   }
}
```

Change Form:

```
<div class="col-md-6">
   <?= $form->field($SasModel, 'semester_id')->dropDownList(SemesterModel::getBatchSemster($SasModel->all_batch_id),
     [ 'prompt'=>'---Select Semester---' ],
     [ 'onchange'=>'this.form.submit()' ],
   ); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: I am having no issues with populating the list of semesters in second dropdown. The issue is with the selected field. I have used "'options' => [$_GET['batchid'] => ['Selected'=>'selected']]," to add selected value in the first dropdown. Everything is working perfect except for the second dropdown selected value.

Comment: @TalhaZahid. it's not about all semester , method get one semester name with matched batch id.

Comment: i tried your suggestions it returned error "Invalid argument supplied for foreach()" in yii2/helpers/BaseHtml.php
foreach ($items as $key => $value) {
            if (is_array($value)) {
                $groupAttrs = isset($groups[$key]) ? $groups[$key] : [];
                $groupAttrs['label'] = $key;
                $attrs = ['options' => $options, 'groups' => $groups, 'encodeSpaces' => $encodeSpaces, 'encode' => $encode];
                $content = static::renderSelectOptions($selection, $value, $attrs);

Comment: okay now no error shows but after changing the 2nd dropdown the form submission is not triggering.

Comment: By tweeking the code to [ 'prompt'=>'---Select Semester---', 'onchange'=>'this.form.submit()' ] the form is triggering. But again once it returns back to the index page where dropdown needs to check for selected value it still doesnt change the value to selected.